# nmake - how to force echo command to output the tab character?

Tags: echo, nmake, control-characters

How to force echo command to output a tab character in MS nmake makefile?
Verbatim tabs inserted right into a string after echo command are removed by nmake and don't show up in the output file.

```
all :
    @echo I WANT TO OUTPUT THE <TAB> CHARACTER HERE! > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable with **TAB** char. Put this lines in your .bat file:

set tab=**[stroke TAB char from your keyboard]**
echo a%tab%b>yourfile.txt

Doing so, yourfile.txt will have text a**[TAB]**b

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can create a file containing the tab character, named input.txt (not using nmake), and then say:

```
all :
    @copy /b input.txt output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have tried to put the tab inside quotes?

```
all:
    @echo "<TAB>" > output.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this. The tab character is then present but quotes also which I don't want since using echo I'm creating another nmake makefile and when quotes are present it doesn't work. I need the tab character alone. Any idea how to avoid outputting quotes in this scenerio?

Answer (score 0):

```
output.txt:
    <<output.txt
I WANT TO OUTPUT THE <TAB> CHARACTER HERE!
<<KEEP
```

`<TAB>` represents a literal tab character here of course.

Answer (score 0):

DOS and Windows have ugly text support in native batch files :).

Here is nice way to do your task:

1. install Python interpretator
2. write simple script which appends character with specified code to file
3. call script wherever you want :)

Simple script:

```
'''
append_char.py - appends character with specified code to end of file

Usage:  append_char.py  filename charcode

'''
import os
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
assert os.path.exists(filename)

charcode = int(sys.argv[2])
assert 0 <= charcode <= 255

fh = open(filename, 'ab')
fh.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
fh.write(chr(charcode))

fh.close()
```

using this script from batch file you can create any possible file in universe :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need. I used the answer using the quotes around the character and just took it one step further.

{tab} means pressing the keyboard tab key in the text editor.

SET tab="{tab}"

SET tab=%tab:~1,1%

The second line extracts the middle character from the quoted string.

Now you can use the %tab% variable with ECHO and, I suspect, anywhere else it's needed.

ECHO %tab%This text is indented, preceded by a tab.

I suspect this technique could be used with other problem characters as well.